# How do I create a commit comment template for ankhsvn?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control, ankhsvn

I'm using AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2008.  I'm looking for a way to setup a default template for every commit comment.  Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real answer here: no there's no support in AnkhSvn to do that. One of the problems for templates like these is that the pending changes window can be open all the time. Filling the commit box with the content of tsvn:logtemplate will have to be done with a context menu / toolbar click.

Can you add a request for this at [our uservoice page](http://ankhsvn.uservoice.com)?

Comment: Made suggestion on the uservoice page.

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the template to the tsvn:logtemplate property of the working copy root folder (e.g., the solution folder), and see if AnkhSVN recognizes it.

If not, maybe consider VisualSVN as an alternative. After evaluating AhkhSVN we decided to use Visual SVN instead, which is a VS plug-in and front end to the free TortoiseSVN. The upside is that you get all of TortoiseSVN's features, including all the custom tsvn: properties. The downside is that it's not free ($49).